# PHP, In a string, how to put two words beside each other or more in parentheses?

Tags: php, regex, string, uppercase

In a string, how to put two words or more which have capital letters beside each other in parentheses. example:

```
   $string = "My name is John Ed, from Canada";
```

The output to be like this: `(My) name is (John Ed), from (Canada)`

Comment: **How can I put the words that have hyphen in between in one parentheses?** example: `The 47-year-old, digs out racy behind-the-scenes snaps from 2007` to be like this: `The (47-year-old), digs out racy (behind-the-scenes) snaps from 2007`

Answer (score 3):

A first idea could look like this:

```
<?php
    $str = "My name is John Ed, from Canada";
    echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]\\w*)/", "($1)", $str); //(My) name is (John) (Ed), from (Canada)
?>
```

The thing with (John Ed) should be a little tricky...

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
<?php
  $str = "My name is John Ed, from Canada and I Do Have Cookies.";
  echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]{1}\w*(\s+[A-Z]{1}\w*)*)/", "($1)", $str); //(My) name is (John Ed), from (Canada) and (I Do Have Cookies).
?>
```

Comment: It works fine :)
In case I want to ignore special charcter that come between tow words, example:

`$string = "My name is John Ed, from Canada, Quebec";`
Your solution will output this:
`(My) name is (John) (Ed), from (Canada), (Quebec)`

And I want it to be like this:
`(My) name is (John) (Ed), from (Canada, Quebec)`

Comment: That's because '\s+' only allows whitespaces between the words. You can extend this part, e.g. '[,\s]+' so that a comma will be included, too.

Comment: COOL, works fine :) your new code is: `echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]{1}\w*([,\s]+[A-Z]{1}\w*)*)/", "($1)", $sentences[$i]);`
Thank you all

Comment: How can I put the words that have hyphen in between in one parentheses? example: `The 47-year-old, digs out racy behind-the-scenes snaps from 2007` to be like this: `The (47-year-old), digs out racy (behind-the-scenes) snaps from 2007`

Comment: `echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]{1}[\w\-]*([,\s]+[A-Z]{1}[\w\-]*)*)/", "($1)", $sentences[$i]);` should do that (not tested).

Comment: The `{1}` quantifiers are needless pattern bloat.

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php
  $str = "My name is John Ed, from Canada";
  echo preg_replace('/([A-Z]\w*(\s+[A-Z]\w*)*)/', "($1)", $str);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be unicode compatible, use the following:

```
$str = 'My name is John Ed, from Canada, Quebec, Saint-Laurent. My friend is Françoise';
echo preg_replace('/(\p{Lu}\pL*(?:[\s,-]+\p{Lu}\pL*)*)/', "($1)", $str);
```

**output:**

```
(My) name is (John Ed), from (Canada, Quebec, Saint-Laurent). (My) friend is (Françoise)
```

**explanation:**

```
(           : start capture group 1
  \p{Lu}    : one letter uppercase
  \pL*      : 0 or more letters
  (?:       : start non capture group
    [\s,-]+ : space, comma or dash one or more times
    \p{Lu}  : one letter, uppercase
    \pL*    : 0 or more letters
  )*        : 0 or more times non capture group
)           : end of group 1
```

See more about [unicode properties](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = "My name is John Ed, from Canada\n";
echo preg_replace("/([A-Z]\\w+( [A-Z]\\w+)*)/", "($1)", $str); //(My) name is (John Ed), from (Canada)
```

Give this a try